# Flask "Hello World" Login Module Not Found Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import

I'm trying to get a basic flask application (app name = app.py) with a simple login to run (in a virtualenv environment, python 3).

```
Structure:
___________
Outer Folder:
|
|--venv
|--__init__.py
|--requirements.txt
|--webapp
|        --__init__.py
|        --app.py
|        --models.py
|        --templates
|                 --login.html
|                 --signup.html
|        --sqldb.db
|        --forms
|                --__init__.py
|                --forms.py
```

Gist of app.py: [gist of app.py minus route logic](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c20521e2426f891fa5f038cd2044cb8d)

The trouble is with this code:

```
from forms.forms import SignupForm
```

Now if I go: `python app.py`
**It works!**

However (after `export FLASK_APP=app.py` ) the command: `flask run`
Gives the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'`

Well, okay, let's change it to have a dot in front:

```
     from .forms.forms import SignupForm
```

NOW, **flask run works**...however: `python app.py` gives:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.forms'; '__main__' is not a package`

*Now, maybe it's a bit unreasonable, but I would like them to both work*. I get that I may be missing something *very* basic here, but I have searched and searched and not found pertaining to this (all google returned was a few issues on github) so please don't be afraid of giving a for dummies type answer!

Imports:
[Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcX5U.png)
InitDB:
[initdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COCgq.png)
Main:
[main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAOe5.png)

Comment: have you tried adding a `__init__.py` file to the directory? That will tell Python to treat this directory as a module.

Comment: Thanks @kstullich . Yes sorry both the main directory with app.py and the forms subdirectory with the forms.py do have an `__init__.py` file. I just used `touch __init__.py` in both cases, was under the impression the file doesn't need to have anything in it?

Comment: Could you show a little bit more of your code? Then probably somebody will help you.

Comment: @Nurjan Sure, but I think this is a problem with imports bc changing that one line fixes it for one (python or flask run) but messed up the other?

Comment: @xCept It is difficult to understand what you're trying to do without code (not all, but least the main parts).

Comment: @Nurjan Thanks. Here's a gist of app.py:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c20521e2426f891fa5f038cd2044cb8d

Comment: @xCept What is the structure of your project? Could you provide full info?